# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;

Tags: java, sorting, vector, comparable, lang

I'm using Eclipse and I'm using Java. My objective it's to **sort** a vector, with the **bogoSort** method
in one vector( **vectorExample** ) adapted to my type of vector and use the **Java sort** on other vector (**javaVector**) and compare them.

I did the tests but it did't work, so I don't know what is failing.
***Note: there are few words in spanish: ordenado = sorted, Ejemplo = Example, maximo = maximun, contenido = content.**

**EjemploVector class**

```
   package vector;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class EjemploVector <T> {
protected T[] contenido;
private int numeroElementos;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public EjemploVector () {
    contenido = (T[]) new Object[100];
    numeroElementos = 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public EjemploVector (int maximo) {
    contenido = (T[]) new Object[maximo];
    numeroElementos = 0;
}

public String toString(){
    String toString="[";
     for (int k=0; k<numeroElementos;k++){
         if (k==numeroElementos-1){
             toString = toString + contenido[k].toString();
         } else {
             toString = toString + contenido[k].toString()+", ";
         }
     }
     toString = toString + "]";
     return toString;
}

public boolean equals (Object derecho){
     if (!(derecho instanceof Vector<?>)) {
         return false;
     } else if (numeroElementos != ((Vector<?>)derecho).size()) {
         return false;
     } else {
         Iterator<?> elemento = ((Vector<?>)derecho).iterator();
         for (int k=0; k<numeroElementos;k++){
             if (!((contenido[k]).equals (elemento.next()))) {
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
     }
}

public void addElement (T elemento){
    contenido[numeroElementos++]= elemento;
}

protected T[] getContenido(){
    return this.contenido;
}

protected T getContenido (int k){
    return this.contenido[k];
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void setContenido (int k, Object elemento){
    this.contenido[k]= (T)elemento;
}
```

> **EjemploVectorOrdenadoClass**

```
package vector.ordenado;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import vector.EjemploVector;

public class EjemploVectorOrdenado<T extends Comparable<T>> extends EjemploVector<T> {

    private boolean organized;

    public EjemploVectorOrdenado() {
        super();
        organized = true;
    }

    public EjemploVectorOrdenado(int maximo) {
        super(maximo);
        organized = true; //
    }

    public boolean getOrdenado() {
        return this.organized;
    }

    // Method bogoSort
    public void bogoSort() {
        if (!this.organized) {

            if (this.size() > 0) {


                Random generator;
                T tempVariable;
                int randomPosition;

                do {
                    generator = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
                        randomPosition = generator.nextInt(this.size());

                        tempVariable = contenido[i];
                        contenido[i] = contenido[randomPosition];
                        contenido[randomPosition] = tempVariable;

                    }
                } while (!organized);

            }

        }
        this.organized = true;
    }

    public void addElement(T elemento) {
        super.addElement(elemento);
        if (organized && this.size() > 1) {
            T penultimo = this.getContenido(this.size() - 2);
            T ultimo = this.getContenido(this.size() - 1);
            organized = penultimo.compareTo(ultimo) <= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**ElementoTest class**

> package elementos;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ElementoTest implements Comparable<ElementoTest>, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7683744298261205956L;

private static int numeroElementosTest = 0;
private int clave;
private int  valor;

public ElementoTest(int i){
    this.clave = i;
    this.valor = numeroElementosTest;
    numeroElementosTest++;
}

public String toString(){
    return ("(" + this.clave + "," + this.valor + ")");
}

public boolean equals (Object derecho){
     if (!(derecho instanceof ElementoTest)) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return clave == ((ElementoTest)derecho).clave;
     }
}

public char getClave(){
      return this.clave;
}

public int getValor(){
      return this.valor;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ElementoTest elemento) {
    if (elemento == null){
        return -1;
    } else if (this.equals(elemento)){
        return 0;
    } else if (clave < elemento.clave){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

**TESTS**
The first it's a stupid test, because it puts elements in order so... really the methods   aren´t doing anything, java just compare and it gives correct

I tried to make an unsorted vector adding elements but there appears the `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.... etc.`

```
package vector.ordenado;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import elementos.ElementoTest;

public class EjemploVectorOrdenadoTest {

    private Vector<ElementoTest> vectorJava;
    private EjemploVectorOrdenado<ElementoTest> vectorExample;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        vectorJava = new Vector<ElementoTest>(100);
        vectorExample = new EjemploVectorOrdenado<ElementoTest>(100);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSortFailTest() {
        for (char c = 'a'; c < 'g'; c++) {
            vectorJava.addElement(new ElementoTest(c));
            vectorExample.addElement(new ElementoTest(c));

        }
        Collections.sort(vectorJava);
        vectorExample.bogoSort();
        assertTrue(vectorExample.equals(vectorJava));
        assertTrue(vectorExample.getOrdenado());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSort() {
        {
            vectorJava.addElement(new ElementoTest(1));
            vectorJava.addElement(new ElementoTest(3));
            vectorJava.addElement(new ElementoTest(2));
            vectorExample.addElement(new ElementoTest(3));
            vectorExample.addElement(new ElementoTest(2));
            vectorExample.addElement(new ElementoTest(1));

        }
        Collections.sort(vectorJava);
        vectorExample.bogoSort();
        assertTrue(vectorExample.equals(vectorJava));
        assertTrue(vectorExample.getOrdenado());
    }
}
```

Sorry, for the problems and thanks.

Comment: Post the full stack trace

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your test class `ElementoTest` should implement the `Comparable` interface. Or you need to provide a `Comparator` during your comparison.

Comment: :/  have this in ElementoTest

public class ElementoTest **implements Comparable<ElementoTest>**, Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -7683744298261205956L;
I'm not sure if you  meant that

Answer (score 1):

Does your class `ElementtoTest` implement `Comparable`?

If not, it needs to.

I'm suspecting it doesn't, because that's exactly what would cause this error. you'll need to add `implements Comparable` and then override the `int compareTo(Elementtotest e)` method, where you specify what criteria you'd like to order the objects based on.

Comment: :/  have this in ElementoTest

public class ElementoTest **implements Comparable<ElementoTest>**, Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -7683744298261205956L;
I'm not sure if you  meant that

Comment: Have you added a method `public int compareTo(ElementoTest)` ?

Comment: And also :
@Override
 public int compareTo(ElementoTest elemento) {
  if (elemento == null){
   return -1;
  } else if (this.equals(elemento)){
   return 0;
  } else if (clave < elemento.clave){
   return -1;
  } else {
   return 1;
  }
 }

Comment: you need to read up on how to write a compareTo() method. Remember, its purpose is to decide how to order a list of objects, usually based on some integral field. That being said, as long as you implement comparable you shouldn't be getting a ClassCastException. Please post the full stack trace (the full error message printed by your IDE)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
 at vector.ordenado.EjemploVectorOrdenado.bogoSort(EjemploVectorOrdenado.java:47)
 at vector.ordenado.EjemploVectorOrdenadoTest.testSort(EjemploVectorOrdenadoTest.java:52)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at

Comment: org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
 at

Comment: org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at

Comment: Ok, you can stop now. For future reference, if it's too long to post in a single comment, edit your original post and put it there. This is telling you that the exception is thrown on line 47. Can you tell me what's on line 47?

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
... sorry if this isn't the good way to put the error -.-

Comment: Ok, you can stop now. For future reference, if it's too long to post in a single comment, edit your original post and put it there. This is telling you that the exception is thrown on line 47. Can you tell me what's on line 47?

Comment: I don't know if you mean line 47 from the test...
vectorExample.addElement(new ElementoTest(2));

Comment: Okay, change the top line of that class to this: `class EjemploVectorOrdenado extends EjemploVector<ElementoTest>`. You don't need to implement Comparable in the tester class. Also, T is sortof like a "placeholder" for generic types - when you create one, you should replace it with actual type you're using.

Comment: If it's still not working, please EDIT YOUR POST (don't put this in comments) and show me the `EjemploVector` class. If the top line reads `class EjemploVector<T>` or `class EjemploVector extends Vector<T>`,  replace it with `class EjemploVector extends Vector <ElementoTest>`

Comment: Pf... I put that and it gives error -.-
PS: i dind´t read that last post sorry
going to edit post.

Comment: Post the ElementoTest class as well.